# Is it better to submit temporary fix/answer as an answer or edit it in the question

Tags: discussion, answers, self-answer

Is it reasonable to answer your own question with a temporary solution? I have a solution that kind of works, but it is lacking some "features". Or otherwise, put the solution in the question? If so, then where in the question would be OK: top or bottom part?

Comment: @Nathan is the capital OK the right? because if you read it, it feels like **screaming**, so I normally use ok.

Comment: Yes. "OK" is one of the few words in the English language that's conventionally written in all-caps, always. It's sort of an acronym, although we don't know for sure what words were used to form it. The same word can also be written "okay" (which follows normal casing rules), but "ok", "Ok", and other variants are all wrong.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Thanks for a reasonable explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The question goes in the question box, and answers (including workarounds) belong in the answer box.

A workaround is a legitimate attempt to "answer" the question, so it should be posted in the answer box. The fact a more complete answer may come along later should not discourage you from posting it there.

You should *not* post any information about how you solved your own problem in the question. That box should only contain the question. Including information about your *attempts to solve the problem on your own* DO belong in the question, but these are never a solution, per se, but rather unsuccessful attempts to find one.